# Generate valid sudoku puzzle in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sudoku

I try to generate a valid sudoku puzzle in C, when i compile, nothing happend, i think there is an infinite loop but I don't know where it can come from! I think I need help! In my reasoning, i try to :
Randomly take any number 1-9.
Check if it is safe to put in the cell.(row , column and box)
If safe, place it and increment to next location and go to step 1.
If not safe, then without incrementing go to step 1.
Once matrix is fully filled, remove k no. of elements randomly to complete game.
Here my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 9 // row and col 
#define SRN 3 // square and row
#define K 20 //missing digits 

int mat[N][N];

bool unUsedInBox(int rowStart, int colStart, int num) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SRN; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < SRN; j++)
      if (mat[rowStart + i][colStart + j] == num)
        return false;

  return true;
}

int randomGenerator(int num) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  return (int) ( rand() % num ) + 1;
}

bool unUsedInRow(int i, int num) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    if (mat[i][j] == num)
      return false;
  return true;
}

// check in the row for existence 
bool unUsedInCol(int j, int num) {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    if (mat[i][j] == num)
      return false;
  return true;
}

bool CheckIfSafe(int i, int j, int num) {
  return (unUsedInRow(i, num) &&
    unUsedInCol(j, num) &&
    unUsedInBox(i - i % SRN, j - j % SRN, num));
}

void fillBox(int row, int col) {
  int num;
  for (int i = 0; i < SRN; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SRN; j++) {
      do {
        num = randomGenerator(N);
      }
      while (!unUsedInBox(row, col, num));

      mat[row + i][col + j] = num;
    }
  }
}

void fillDiagonal() {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + SRN)
    fillBox(i, i);
}

bool fillRemaining(int i, int j) {
  if (j >= N && i < N - 1) {
    i = i + 1;
    j = 0;
  }
  if (i >= N && j >= N)
    return true;

  if (i < SRN) {
    if (j < SRN)
      j = SRN;
  } else if (i < N - SRN) {
    if (j == (int)(i / SRN) * SRN)
      j = j + SRN;
  } else {
    if (j == N - SRN) {
      i = i + 1;
      j = 0;
      if (i >= N)
        return true;
    }
  }

  for (int num = 1; num <= N; num++) {
    if (CheckIfSafe(i, j, num)) {
      mat[i][j] = num;
      if (fillRemaining(i, j + 1))
        return true;

      mat[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void removeKDigits() {
  int count = K;
  while (count != 0) {
    int cellId = randomGenerator(N * N);

    int i = (cellId / N);
    int j = cellId % 9;
    if (j != 0)
      j = j - 1;

    if (mat[i][j] != 0) {
      count--;
      mat[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

void fillValues() {
  // Fill the diagonal of SRN x SRN matrices 
  fillDiagonal();

  // Fill remaining blocks 
  fillRemaining(0, SRN);

  // Remove Randomly K digits to make game 
  removeKDigits();
}

void printSudoku() {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        printf("%d",mat[i][j]);
        printf(" ");
    }
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  fillValues();
  printSudoku();
}
```

Comment: To begin with, only call `srand` *once*.

Comment: Or just refrain from using the default random, it's pretty bad.

Comment: *i think there is an infinite loop but I don't know where it can come from!* - this is where a debugger could help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to use the debugger: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: After OP sucessfully used debugger and found out where the program loops, the question **why** it happens would be appropriate, but it would be a separate question.

Comment: @SergeyA the problem here that the issue will not be easily reproducible with a debugger. It is timing-dependent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.  
See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: More to the point, *why* don't you know where you have an infinite loop, or whether you have one at all?  As the guidelines show, we *expect* you to perform "due diligence" before you post here.  If nothing else, put in `print` statements to trace the data and logic flow.  Posting your entire program exercise without any debugging attempt is beyond the posting guidelines.  Do your part, and we'll be happy to do ours.

Comment: @Prune I was able to reproduce the problem directly from the code as posted. Expected and actual output are also clear (a valid sudoku puzzle and nothing, respectively). This is an MCVE if I ever saw one. Furthermore, debugging a timing-dependent problem, of which this is an example, could be rather frustrating even for seasoned developers. Is it reasonable to request that one shows their debugging effort if we know that it is very likely to be fruitless?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the infinite loop is caused by:

```
int randomGenerator(int num) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  return (int) ( rand() % num ) + 1;
}
```

Because `srand` is called for the generation of every "random" number, the same number will be generated over and over again. Since that number will already be in use, the loop `while (!unUsedInBox(row, col, num));` will loop forever (or at least until `time(NULL)` returns a new value). So every second (about the resultion of `time`) there will be one step progress, and then another second need to pass, etcetera, seeming to take infinitely.

<sup>(See comment by Some programmer dude)</sup>

Comment: Minor: Resolution of `(unsigned) time_t` is more often 1 sec than 17ms. ,  Still UV